# Javascript and CSS working on Firefox but not working on IE

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser

I have this code which working on Firefox but not working on IE missing last character on IE

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>wrapped</title>   
      <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">  
       function set_padd(){   
        var tt = document.getElementById("span_padding").innerHTML;    
        var txt = new Array();     
     txt = tt.split(" ");                 
        var atxt = '';
        var f_txt = '';
        var wrd_pr_linr = 4;    
        var cnt = 1;     
        for(var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++){ 
          if(txt[i].length > 0){           
           txt[i] = txt[i].replace(' ','');
           if(cnt < wrd_pr_linr){
            if(txt[i].length > 0){
           atxt += ' '+txt[i].replace(' ','');
           cnt++;          
            }
           }else{
            f_txt += '<a class="padd_txt" >'+atxt+'</a><br />';
            atxt = ''; 
            cnt = 1;
           }
          }
        }  
        document.getElementById("span_padding").innerHTML = f_txt;  
       }  
      </script>  
      <style type="text/css">  
       .padd_txt{padding:7px;background:#009;color:#FFF;line-height:26px;font-size:14px;} 

  body{font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:24px; line-height:1.2em;}
  span{background-color: #009; width:200px; color: #FFF;" class="blocktext;}



      </style>
</head> 
<body onload="set_padd();">
  <div style="width: 350px;"> 
      <p>
      <span id="span_padding">
          This is what I want to 
       happen where one
       long string is wrapped 
       and the text has this 
       highlight color behind 
       it. 
      </span>  
   </div>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Output on Firefox is:

> This is
>   I want to
>   happen where one
>   string is wrapped
>   and the text
>   this highlight
>   behind it.

and output on IE:

> This is what
>   want to happen
>   one long string
>   wrapped and the
>   has this highlight

missing last two words.

Comment: It looks like it doesn't work on either browser properly, words are missing from both outputs.

Comment: you should try to the your code a bit more readable, so ppl don't have to be guessing what you want to store in each var

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The results are different on IE and Firefox because of IE's habit of throwing away whitespace around tags. But your function is broken on both browsers, as it throws away the last word of each line and potentially the whole last line without ever outputting it.

Seems a bit laborious too. How about using a regex to match each group of up to four words:

```
function set_padd() {
    var span= document.getElementById('span_padding');
    var text= span.firstChild.data;
    span.innerHTML= '';
    var lines= text.match(/\S+(\s+\S+){0,3}/g);

    for (var i= 0; i<lines.length; i++) {
        var el= document.createElement('a');
        el.className= 'padd_txt';
        el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(lines[i]));
        span.appendChild(el);
        span.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, I hope you don't mind I borrowed most of your regex to improve the last part of my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are several obvious problems with your code:

- In your `i`, where `cnt < wrd_pr_linr` is false, you're resetting the count and wrapping  a span around the current `atxt`, but you're not doing anything with `txt[i]`, so it's missed off as the increment increases on the next turn around.  You could fix this by adding `i--;` after `cnt++;`.
- If your loop terminates whilst `cnt < wrd_pr_linr` is true, your else statement that creates the DOM string will not be executed and the value of `atxt` is just ignored.  You need to run the same code block when your if statement is about to terminate.

If it were me, I'd look into a much neater, simpler, regex based solution:

```
function set_padd(){   
    var f_txt;
    var tt = document.getElementById("span_padding").innerHTML;

    // replace every third space with "{!BREAK!}"    
    tt = tt.replace(/(.*?\s+.*?\s+.*?)\s+/g, "$1{!BREAK!}");

    // Splitting on that string creates an array with 3 words in each index
    tArr = tt.split("{!BREAK!}");

    // Join the array again with the HTML you need between each index
    f_txt = tArr.join('</a><br/><a class="padd_txt">');

    // Wrap the text with the start tag and the end tag
    f_txt = '<a class="padd_txt">' + f_txt + '</a>';

    // Viola!
    document.getElementById("span_padding").innerHTML = f_txt;  
}
```

Take out the comments, swap the regex for something similar to [bobince's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682108/javascript-and-css-working-on-firefox-but-not-working-on-ie/2682407#2682407) and you can get it to look really small:

```
function set_padd(){   
    var tt = document.getElementById("span_padding").innerHTML;
    var f_txt = '<a class="padd_txt">'
              + tt.match(/\S+(\s+\S+){0,2}/g)
                  .join('</a><br/><a class="padd_txt">')
              + '</a>';

    document.getElementById("span_padding").innerHTML = f_txt;  
}
```